# SQL Oracle merging 2 queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two queries and I have to merge them, can you help me?

```
select sledovanost.ID_D,tv_stanice.ID_STA,tv_stanice.NAZOV_STANICE
from sledovanost
left outer join tv_stanice
on (sledovanost.id_sta=tv_stanice.id_sta);

select divak.MENO
from sledovanost
left outer join divak
on (sledovanost.ID_D=divak.ID_D);
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean by "merge"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding the underlying data structure and desired results, the most likely approach would be chaining the `left join`s:

```
select s.ID_D, t.ID_STA, t.NAZOV_STANICE, d.MENO
from sledovanost s left outer join
     tv_stanice t
     on s.id_sta = t.id_sta left outer join
     divak d
     on s.ID_D = d.ID_D;
```

Comment: @RichardFriedl - You still haven't explained what you meant by "merge". As it is now, your question and Gordon's answer will be useful to you and to nobody else. Please make the effort to explain what you meant by editing your original post, even if you have the answer now.

Comment: First querie has 2 columns. First has only numbers and second one only names. Second querie is the same. My task was to split(merge) these queries into one.